# Using dictionary within structures

Tags: vb.net

I have a structure that has a string and 2 dictionary variable. I don't know how to insert data into these dictionaries.

```
Public Structure librariesWithMedia
    Dim strLibraryName As String
    Dim dicBooksMedia As SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim dicNonBooksMedia As SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
End Structure
Dim libraryMediaEntry As librariesWithMedia
```

This is my structure and this is how I'm storing the values.

```
libraryMediaEntry.dicBooksMedia.Add(key, value)
```

This gives me a null reference exception error. Can anyone help me understand and how I would have to take the data?

Comment: That is not VBA. Maybe VB.Net

Comment: `dicBooksMedia` doesn't exist within your struct until you set it to an object

Comment: Probably should be a `Class` rather than `Structure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Structure MUST initialise/instantiate the dictionaries before you can use them.

```
Public Structure librariesWithMedia
  '
  Dim strLibraryName As String
  Dim dicBooksMedia As SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
  Dim dicNonBooksMedia As SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
  '
  Sub New(LibName As String)
    strLibraryName = LibName
    dicBooksMedia = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
    dicNonBooksMedia = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
  End Sub
  '
End Structure
'
Dim libraryMediaEntry As librariesWithMedia
```

And then in your code, for example

```
Sub DoSomethingProcess()
  '
  libraryMediaEntry = New librariesWithMedia("Featured_Books")
  libraryMediaEntry.dicBooksMedia.Add("James A Michener", "Chesapeake")
  '
End Sub
```